# How to add multiple row in datatable using LinQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, uipath

I have 2 datatable dtMaster and dtResult

dtMaster

```
No Name    Address        Status
1  Andy    Sesame Street  Valid
2  Justin  Guava Street   Invalid
3  Taylor  West Street    Valid
```

If Status = Valid, I want to add 2 different rows in another datatable with template

```
No Name              Address
1  Ms. Julie         dtMaster("Address")
2  dtMaster("Name")  dtMaster("Address")
```

Expected Result is
dtResult

```
No Name      Address
1  Ms. Julie Sesame Street  --> from 1st row in dtMaster
2  Andy      Sesame Street  --> from 1st row in dtMaster
1  Ms. Julie West Street    --> from 3rd row in dtMaster
2  Taylor    West Street    --> from 3rd row in dtMaster
```

I tried this code, but it gives the type of ra1 (array) instead of the value I want, how to say :D

```
(From row1 In dtMaster
Let ra1 = {({"1","Ms. Julie",row1("Address")}),({"2",row1("Name"),row1("Address")})}
Select If(row1("Status").tostring="Valid",dtResult.Rows.Add(ra1),dtResult.Rows.Add(row1.itemArray))
).copytodatatable
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? This is not a place where you tell us what you want done and we do it for you. If you want to use LINQ, you have to learn how to use LINQ and then use it. If what you try doesn't work, then you need to show us what you did and explain exactly how it doesn't behave to your expectations.

Comment: @jmcilhinney   i edited my question, i already put my tried code there

Comment: *"i tried this code"*. And what happened that you didn't expect or didn't happen that you did expect?

Answer (score 0):

`System.Data.DataTable` iteration is like this

```
' Declare DataTable
Dim dtResult As New DataTable()
' Define columns
dtResult.Columns.Add("No", GetType(System.Int32))
dtResult.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(System.String))
dtResult.Columns.Add("Address", GetType(System.String))

Dim index As Integer = 1;
For Each row As DataRow In dtMaster.Rows
  If row.Items("Status") = "Valid" Then
    ' Add a row of data
    dtResult.Rows.Add(index, row.Items("Name"), row.Items("Address"))
    index += 1
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to avoid for each because the data is too large. So I need to execute it with LinQ

Comment: @Panda, what does the size of the data have to do with anything? LINQ is not magic. It is a way to write code more succinctly in many cases but it generally performs a little worse than the alternative. Calling `CopyToDataTable` is easy but, behind the scenes, it's still got to create a `DataTable` and add rows to it in a loop. It's just being done for you rather than your doing it yourself.